# forward-comment doesn't move the point

Tags: sexp

I tried running `(forward-comment -1)` by eval command, when the point is actually in the middle of a comment. Like forward-word (or) forward-line, i expected it move to the beginning of the comment & then to the previous comment etc...

But, the point is not moving at all..

Like, my javascript snippet looks like,

```
    /*  this is a dummy comment
   this is additional(^) comment
this is more additional  comment*/
```

My cursor is on the second line denoted by caret symbol and then i run, `(forward-comment -1)` and i expect the point to move to the comment's beginning. But `(point)` has not changed at all.

Note: This behavior is noticed in elisp mode as well with semicolon-ed comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's the way `forward-comment` works (likewise `forward-sexp`).

To quote Stefan, from part of [bug #8667](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=8667):

> The forward-THINGY functions all share the following property AFAIK:
>   when called with a positive argument with point *before* some
>   THINGIES, they will skip over that many THINGIES and when called
>   with a negative argument with point *after* some THINGIES they will
>   skip over that many THINGIES.
>
> E.g. just like forward-comment, forward-sexp from within a sexp will not
>   skip to the end of that sexp.  And just like forward-sexp,
>   forward-comment called in front of a nested comment will jump over that
>   nested comment.
>
> All calls with point elsewhere than before/after a THINGY behave in
>   somewhat arbitrary ways which mostly depend on how the function is
>   implemented and what kind of structure  have (e.g. can they
>   nest?  Can we easily tell when we're in the middle of a THINGY ?).